# Visual Studio for Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8

I've been learning C# for a couple of months now using a text editor, Notepad. I run my code on Command Line.

I tried installing Visual Studio, but a keep getting a response that it's not available for Windows 8 asking me to upgrade to Windows 8.1.

I can't upgrade to Windows 8.1 at the moment, any suggestions on which version of Visual Studio I can use with Win 8 and links to download and install please.

Comment: How were you compiling your code when using notepad?

Comment: Also which version of VS are you talking about?  VS2017 has a minimum requirement of windows 8.1, so you're out of luck there.  But you might want to try VS2015, and if that doesn't work then I know for certain that VS2012 works on Win8 because I used to work with that combination of IDE/OS

Comment: I did some tweak. .Net normally comes with windows so I changed the path of the external variables

Comment: Can't really explain, but can sure give am illustration... Pictorial

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could always look at the system requirements for each version of Visual Studio:

[Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs)

- Windows 10 version 1507 or higher: Home, Professional, Education, and Enterprise (LTSB and S are not supported)
- Windows Server 2016: Standard and Datacenter
- Windows 8.1 (with Update 2919355): Core, Professional, and Enterprise
- Windows Server 2012 R2 (with Update 2919355): Essentials, Standard, Datacenter
- Windows 7 SP1 (with latest Windows Updates): Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate

[Visual Studio 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs)

- Windows 10
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 8
- Windows 7 SP 1
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

[Visual Studio 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2013-sysrequirements-vs)

- Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 8.1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
- Windows Server 2012 (x64)
- Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)

---

So, of the "recent" versions, Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 should work.